# Spam Filtering using Text Categorization

Tags: machine-learning, email-spam, spam-prevention

I am trying to build spam filtering application using text categorization. From where should I start learning the  algorithms? Which algorithm should I implement first? Anyone can suggest any good material?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest one to start with is Naive Bayes.

http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/naive-bayes-text-classification-1.html

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](http://ats.cs.ut.ee/u/kt/hw/spam/spam.pdf) [PDF] that gives quite a good overview of available machine learning techniques and their performance for spam filtering.

[Here](http://www.esp.uem.es/jmgomez/spam/index.html) you can find more information on the subject as well as training data!

I must say that there are volumes of material online, simple google search for "spam filtering machine learning techniques" is enough.

Comment: thanx a lot.... i would be glad if you could help me with the work in further progress..